# How to populate a field in a specific model? (mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I use mongodb.

I want to populate the 'star' field in the review into the Sweet model.

My goal is to get ranking like this and format these codes and return the ranking.

```
  {name: "kitkat",evaluation:4.7},
  {name: "candy",evaluation:4.5},
  {name: "jagariko",evaluation:4.1},
  {name: "nicestick",evaluation:3.7},
  {name: "highchu",evaluation:2.7},
  {name: "vegetableman",evaluation:1.2},
```

This is my code.

```
Review.ts

import {Description, Required} from "@tsed/schema";
import {Model, ObjectID, Ref} from "@tsed/mongoose";
import {Reply} from "./Reply";
import {User} from "./User";
import { Sweet } from './Sweet';

@Model()
export class Review{
    @ObjectID("id")
    _id: string;
...
    // this is the field i want to get
    @Description("Star")
    @Required()
    star: Number;
}

SweetsService.ts

  // i am going to format ranking this function 
  async getRanking(){
    console.log('hoge')
    const ranking = await this.Sweet.find({}).populate('review')
    return ranking
  }

SweetsRankingCtrl.ts
// this is endpoint
@Controller("/ranking")
export class SweetsRankingCtrl {
  constructor(private SweetsService: SweetsService,private ReviewsService: ReviewsService) {}
  @Get("/")
  async getRanking() {
    const ranking = await this.SweetsService.getRanking()
    console.log(ranking)
    return sweetsRanking;
  }
```

Thank you.